# EF CORE "dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold" Define Data Types

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-6

I've been searching the web for a while, but can't find what I'm looking for.

Basically when I run the aforementioned code against my Sqlite DB, it generates all the classes etc, but instead of rendering booleans etc, it chooses to create them as byte[] and all floating point numbers come through as doubles.

I don't want this, as doubles tend to do poorly when doing math against them, and can create incorrect values.

So basically what I want to know, is, is there a way to define the mapping of types.  So all "REAL" in the database are created as Decimal and BIT as bool?

Comment: Did you mean to say `byte[]`? What are the types in SQL?

Comment: I did, yes.

It's Sqlite, so TEXT, INTEGER (which comes through as long), REAL, BIT & BLOB.  

Also have the issue of dates being stored as text, which is another issue.

Comment: *dates being stored as text* - but isn't that par for the course with SQLite?

Comment: Are you really using EF6 together with netcore? Or did you mean to tag ef-core-6

Comment: It's a .NET 6.0 Web Api.  Just happens to have a Sqlite DB, and I was sick of manually editing the DBContext when new columns were added. Trying to EF Core to generate them, if I can manage to get the data types to play nice.

Comment: Use a properly typed database engine

Comment: It's not up to me, but thanks for your advice